# Input inside div not clickable

Tags: html, css, mustache

I can't make these inputs clickable

Every item must be clickable and pass input value "id" to form action route

```
<form action="/rodada/">
 {{#musicas.1}}
 {{#.}}
 <div class="opcao">
  {{titulo}} - {{artista}}
  <input id="opcao" class="shh" type="submit" name="musicaAtual" value=" 
  {{idTrackDeezer}}">
 </div>
 {{/.}}
 {{/musicas.1}}
</form>
```

css:

```
#wp-respostas{
    margin-top: 8%;
}
.opcao{
    background-color: #fba69d;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 4px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.shh{
    display: none !important;
}
```

FINAL RESULT (not clickable)

[image]

Working code (thanks, Dan Oswalt):

```
{{#musicas.1}}
{{#.}}
<div class="opcao" onclick="window.open('/rodada/?id={{idTrackDeezer}}', '_self');">
{{titulo}} - {{artista}}
</div>
{{/.}}
{{/musicas.1}}
```

Comment: what do you want to happen when you click it?

Comment: form route action="/rodada/" should be called (passing id from value)

Comment: do they have to be in a form? to do what you want, and only send one of the inputs, you'll have to override the default behavior of a form submission. At that point, you may not want to use a form, but an onclick function that does an AJAX POST request to that endpoint.

Comment: They were a list of links, but I had problems calling route that way, so I changes. I was trying to avoid ajax, is that really the only way?

Comment: or, if it's ok to just to a GET request, you can do it without ajax, just calling onclick="window.open(<endpoint>/?id=<title>)";

Comment: ajax is not the only way to POST, the other way is to do an onclick to run a function that creates a new form and submits that one value, I suppose.

Comment: ok, i added window.open to div, but i still can't click (sorry to post code here)<div class="opcao" onclick="window.open('/rodada/?id='{{idTrackDeezer}}')";>
                                    {{titulo}} - {{artista}}
                                    <input id="opcao" class="shh" type="submit" name="musicaAtual">
                                </div>

Comment: try removing the single quotes after `id=`.

Comment: sorry, `onclick="window.location = '/rodada/?id={{idTrackDeezer}}'";` to stay on page

Comment: yes, it's working (I have a new problem, but i's different, something wrong with my route. Thank you!!!

Comment: ok cool, i'm gonna make that the answer if you can accept!

Comment: sure, i will, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GET request is ok, try attaching

`onclick="window.location = '/rodada/?id={{idTrackDeezer}}'";`

or

`onclick="window.open('/rodada/?id={{idTrackDeezer}}')";`

to the div instead of trying to use a form.

Otherwise, for POST, you'll have to use AJAX or do some workaround to create a form and submit the value.